# Is my version of SSH, OpenSSH or some other garden variety?

Tags: ssh

[My WD Mycloud device is running SSH.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C7JIO5Y)    Is there a simple command line test to confirm the version and type of SSH (OpenSSH?)?

```
root@WDMyCloud root # ps -A | grep ssh
 1743 root      4608 S    /usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config
18837 root      7680 S    sshd: root@ttyp1
18944 root      2592 S    grep ssh
20065 root      7680 S    sshd: root@ttyp0
25219 root      4544 S    ssh rchiu@192.168.8.1

root@WDMyCloud root # uname -a
Linux WDMyCloud 3.10.39 #1 SMP Sun Aug 2 12:24:50 CST 2015 2014T20p4 Build-git3e9fe59 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, but here goes.

`ssh -V` to display your ssh client version.

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
$
```

`telnet localhost 22` to display your ssh server version.

```
$ telnet localhost 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
```